# Cannot find module 'semver' When installing Npm

Tags: node.js

This is the error i got when try to install npm. 
please help me to fix it.

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\maheshig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Comment: I followed These steps and it solved my issue

1.uninstall Node.js
2.Remove the content of the following folders
       C:\Users<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
       C:\Users<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm
       C:\Program Files\nodejs
3.Then again install Node https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Since you've already solved the issue, please consider adding it as the solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I followed These steps and it solved my issue

1. uninstall Node.js
2. Remove the content of the following folders
      C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
      C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm
      C:\Program Files\nodejs
3. Then again install Node https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 2):

In linux you can use the following

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/
```

or wherever your global node_modules are

then reinstall npm

this solved the problem with me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a version manager, nvm. It seemed to be some incompatibility between the node version and the npm version I was trying to install.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.